# create a category/subcategory menu in node.js the values should come from Mongo db data base

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm new in node.js and mongodb.I need to create a menu in node.js and the values should come from the mongodb database. I have done this as follows by calling category and sub category in each route.

```
collection = db.collection('category');
collection.find({"status" : "A"}).toArray(function(err, menucategory) {
    collection = db.collection('subcategory');
    collection.find({"status" : "A"}).toArray(function(err, menusubcategory) {
        res.render(
            'home',
            {
                title : 'home', 
                menucategory : menucategory,
                menusubcategory : menusubcategory
            }
        );
    });
});
```

Please help me to do this easily by calling once the data from database and populate the menu.

Comment: As the data is present in two different collections, it is not straight forward. You can take a look at $lookup aggregate operator. It may solve your problem. Please assess for your requirement.

Comment: You can use one collection and add property *parent* to each category. And in for loop build the menu.